# Cannot Install p7zip in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04, 7zip

Currently i am using an instance on Google cloud platform and in Ubuntu 16.04 I am able to install p7zip to extract `.7z` files, but on Ubuntu 18.04 I get the following error:

```
Package p7zip-full is not available, but is referred to by another
package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'p7zip-full' has no installation candidate
```

Bearing in mind that I do not have a GUI, do I have any other option to extract `.7z` archives in Ubuntu 18.04?

I tried to install it using this command

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

But it does not work for 18.04.

Comment: `pz7ip-full` is in universe. Enable it and try again.

Comment: Ok.I will try this and then i will let you guys know.Thank you for all the help

Comment: @DhruvMarwha : did you try? is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: @DhruvMarwha: here is my log: https://gist.github.com/longtth/8316a73cbe4f212cb550e1d4c91498f1

Comment: @Luke i saw your error.In the above link given by you,i have posted something.Do check it.

Comment: @DhruvMarwha thanks, sorry for late reply, i did `sudo apt-get update` and it works now.